# Ejecutar Python desde PHP Windows 10

Tags: php, python

He descargado python 2.7 y se ha instalado en C:\python27

He creado "MiPython.py" :

```
def saludar(): 
 print "Que alegria que alboroto otro perrito piloto"


saludar()
```

**Si lo ejecuto dentro de la carpeta C:\python27 funciona** si lo pongo en otro sitio no funciona... el CMD dice :

```
No se reconoce el comando interno o externo,
```

Y la otra cuestión:
Con ese archivo en  C:\python27 en mi PHP tengo :

```
   shell_exec('C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\MiPython.py') ; 

   tambien he probado con:

   shell_exec('C:\Python27\MiPython.py');
```

Básicamente quiero que en el PHP se abra el cmd y diga eso y que no tenga que estar en la ruta del C:\Python27\ pero no lo consigo ...

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que al momento de instalar Python no lo agregaste al path.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mi lo más práctico es que lo desintales y lo vuelvas a instalar seleccionado esta opción.